# Shopware 6 - store-api list orders with associated documents

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

Using Shopware 6 store-api, I want a list of orders with associated documents. I submit a POST the `store-api/order` endpoint with this body:

```json
{
    "includes": {
        "order": [
            "orderNumber",
            "documents"
        ]
    },
    "associations": {
        "documents": []
    }
}
```

However, the response just shows empty arrays for the documents.

```json
{
    "apiAlias": "order-route-response-struct",
    "orders": {
        "elements": [
            {
                "orderNumber": "SW1001",
                "documents": [],
                "apiAlias": "order"
            },
            {
                "orderNumber": "SW1002",
                "documents": [],
                "apiAlias": "order"
            }
        ],
        "aggregations": [],
        "page": 1,
        "limit": 100,
        "entity": "order",
        "total": 2,
        "states": [],
        "apiAlias": "dal_entity_search_result"
    },
    "paymentChangeable": []
}
```

In Shopware Admin I can verify that both orders do have associated invoices.

How can I enforce the response to contain the information for the associated orders?

Answer (score 0):

For a document to be included in the response to the `store-api/order` endpoint,

1. the document must have been sent to the customer and
2. the document type settings in admin must specify 'Display document in "My Account"' (see screenshot).

[image: How to configure documents in Admin]

Note that the latter (2.) has to take place before (!) a document is created, the setting will have no effect for existing documents.